# Multiple php form buttons

Tags: php, forms

I want to format these as buttons in a form.

```
<p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=moveForward" ?>">forward</a></p>
<p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=moveBackward" ?>">backward</a></p>
<p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=moveLeft" ?>">left</a></p>
<p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=moveRight" ?>">right</a></p>
```

Something like this...

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
<input type="submit" name="moveForward" value="forward">
<input type="submit" name="moveBack" value="back">
<input type="submit" name="moveLeft" value="left">
<input type="submit" name="moveRight" value="right"> 
</form>
```

Comment: PS. you have an HTML-injection hole leading to potential cross-site-scripting attack. All variables output into an HTML file, including `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, need to be wrapped in `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="moveForward">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="moveBack">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="moveLeft">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="moveRight">
```